# Python: accessing elements of a list within a combination of lists

Tags: python, list

I am new to python and I have spent hours trying to figure out the following problem. I have an object that looks like this

```
>> new_list=['abscd','qrtye']['fghtj', 'wert']...more lists
>> type(new_list)

<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
...
```

I would like to access each string within each list. I tried a for-loop and to use .split() as in:

```
>> for l in new_list:
>>     l.split()
```

but I can't access the two strings separately within list l. Any help will be appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect.  `new_list=['abscd','qrtye']['fghtj', 'wert']` --> `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`

Comment: your `new_list` isn't valid python (even if we remove the `...more lists` part).  Can you please post a minimal working example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: dear @PaoloP, please accept one of the answers, if you think they were helpful to you. Thanks! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you have an iterable which yields 2-element lists when iterating.  If so, you can unpack those 2-element lists in your for loop:

```
>>> data = ["foo","bar"],["baz","qux"]
>>> for s1,s2 in data:
...     print s1, "Hello", s2
... 
foo Hello bar
baz Hello qux
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your lists into a 'parent' list, and there you go, it's something like:

```
new_list = [['abscd', 'qrtye'], ['fghtj', 'wert']]
for sub_list in new_list:
    for string in sub_list:
        # do something with string
```

Or with generator expressions:

```
for string in (string for sub_list in new_list for string in sub_list):
    # do something with string
```

Comment: It seems to me that your generator expression isn't doing anything ... and your `new_list` still has a `TypeError`

Comment: Ugh.  Don't do that nested generator expression thing.  That's hideously unreadable.